# Is it correct to say, that in International Law, the legislature consists of the nation-states and they are the ones subject to the laws do enacted?

Tags: international

In International law, the subjects, unlike that of national law, are the nation-states themselves. In this way, can we say that in temporal law here,  there being no higher power, must be horizontal here rather than the vertical form it takes within a nation-state. Then we ought to consider nation-states in toto, as the *de facto* legislature, even if not *de jure*; that is in customary and positive law, as opposed to law itself.

**Q. Is this an accurate description of how international law differed from domestic law in nation-states?**

Answer (score 2):

### No

International law is a web of multilateral and bilateral treaties and custom. There is no legislature, there are merely sovereign states agreeing between themselves what the law is.

Comment: Or Rather: should be in many cases, then the members build on that for national laws